# Geometric Sum and Convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, geometric-series

Suppose I have an infinite sum like
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2^n $$ which diverges.

I want to know what is the limit of the following sum
$$ \lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} 2^n}{2^N-1}$$

One may argue that 
$$ \lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} 2^n}{2^N-1} = 
 \lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{2^N - 1}{2^N-1} = \lim_{N\to\infty} 1 = 1$$
However, 
if we write
$$ \lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \frac{2^n}{2^N-1} $$ 
The sum fails to pass the ratio test because $2^{n+1}/2^n = 2 > 1$
which suggests that series is divergent.

How should I rigorously understand this?

Comment: The numerator equals the denominator, so your limit is $$\lim_{N \to \infty} 1,$$ and that's 1.  In general, if $f(N) \to \infty$ and $g(N) \to \infty$, then it's not necessarily the case that $\lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{f(N)}{g(N)}$ doesn't exist.  For example, take $f(N)=2N$ and $g(N)=3N-17$.  Then the limit is $\frac{2}{3}$.

Comment: Note that $\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} 2^n=2^N-1$

Comment: Sorry, I should edit this question. I think that's not the point

Comment: @Dzoooks I think that main concern I have is that if I put the denominator into the sum, it fails the ratio test.

Comment: @Tom  The ratio test is for series.  $\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \frac{2^n}{2^N-1}$ is not a series.

Comment: @Dzooks https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test $a_n=2^n/(2^N-1)$

Comment: @Tom: You are only summing a finite number of terms ($N$). You have a different set of terms $a_n$ for each $N$. A series has an infinite number of terms that do not change with the number of terms summed.

Comment: @robjohn Ahhhh okay! Thank you!

Comment: @robjohn but say if I interchange the summation and limit, we get completely different result.

Comment: @Tom you cannot interchange the summation and limit since the variable $N$, which you are taking to its limit, is part of the summation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have pointed out, you cannot apply the ratio test to a finite sum. In the limit, the ratio test would be:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\dfrac{\displaystyle \lim_{N \to \infty}\tfrac{2^{n+1}}{2^N-1}}{\displaystyle \lim_{N \to \infty} \tfrac{2^n}{2^N-1}} \to \dfrac{0}{0}\text{ which is undefined}$$

You were trying to take the limit of the finite ratios, which is not the same as the limit of the limit ratio. In other words, the Ratio Test does not apply/cannot be used for this series.